# How to check if a date occurred more than 1 year ago in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have the following code:

```
var consentedOnDate = GetConsentedOn(consent.Id);
var declinedOnDate = GetConsentDeclinedOn(consent.Id);
                
var userHasGivenConsentLessThan1YearAgo = consentedOnDate != null && (consentedOnDate.Value - DateTime.Now.Date).TotalDays < -365;
var userHasDeclinedConsentLessThan1YearAgo = declinedOnDate != null && (declinedOnDate.Value - DateTime.Now.Date).TotalDays < -365;
```

I want the `userHasGivenConsentLessThan1YearAgo` and `userHasDeclinedConsentLessThan1YearAgo` variables to be true if the `consentedOnDate` and `declinedOnDate` are OVER 1 year old from today, but the logic as I has it doesn't seem to be working - have I got this correct? By not working I mean that it says true when should be false, and vice versa.

Comment: Why don't you just use `var consentOneYearAgo = consentedOnDate < Datetime.Now.AddYears(-1)`?(Comparing with null returns false)

Comment: seems to work https://dotnetfiddle.net/vH5zyM

Comment: @ChrᴉzsupportsMonica is that if the consentedOnDate IS over a year old?

Comment: @Jordan1993 This returns true if the date of consent is older than now(!) one year ago. If you want to make it daywise only count days, so today in the early morning should be false, use DateTime.Today. If you're still not convinced try it with some edge cases like 16.11.2020, 18.11.2020 00:00:00, 18.11.2020 20:00:00 and 25.11.2020 and see the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your code and use built-in DateTime-methods:

```
var consentDate = GetConsentedOn(consent.Id);
var consentDeclinedDate = GetConsentDeclinedOn(consent.Id);
                
var isConsentMoreThan1YearAgo = consentDate  < DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1);
var hasDeclinedMoreThan1YearAgo = consentDeclinedDate < DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1);
```

If today is the 1st of October 2020, this will return `true` if the variable consentDate is *earlier than* `01.10.2020 00:00:00` (date and time) and else `false`. False cases would include `01.10.2020 00:00:00`, `20.10.2020 00:00:00` and `consentDate` being `null`.

Please also note the new names of the variables, i.e. booleans beginning with "is" or "has".

Comment: Though be aware of what this does on [February 29th](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addyears?view=net-5.0#remarks) and check it's good enough for your purposes. I.e. it would return false if `consentDate` was the 28th February last year.